# Custom ActionFilterAttribute(authorization) doesn't stop route executing after unauthorized actioncontext response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I am using an `ActionFilterAttribute` to implement a custom authorization that will decorate some of my Routes.
In case the conditions for not being authorized are met, I'm trying to return an Unauthorized response.

```
public override async void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext){
.......

if(myCustomCondition)
  actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
```

The response is indeed set as expected, but after this it continues executing the code in the route.
I've also tried as

```
actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)401) { ReasonPhrase = "Some reason"};
```

but I've got the same behaviour.

How should I set the response so that the rest of the code is not executed(as is not authorized per my conditions) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it continues executing the code in the *route*"? By setting the `Response` property as you're doing the controller's action should not be executed.

Comment: I was expecting that as well, but the action is executed

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your filter can you check if the execution flow executes the statement where you set the response? And how are you applying the filter to the desired action /controller?

Comment: Yes, the statement is reached. I'm applying the filter individually to the desired routes ("decorating").

Comment: I have changed to OnActionExecutingAsync and it works as expected.